# Causes of dB level increasing over distance from source?

Tags: acoustics, data

I was given some data taken from three microphones placed at three different distances (25, 50, 100 ft) from the railroad track. The sound level increases by 7 dB from 25 to 50 feet and about 1.5 dB from 50 to 100 feet.

I understand that this flies in the face of how this sort of thing *should* happen, and yes, I have checked the documentation to make sure I didn't get the microphones mixed up. Added to this that the data collector remembers placing the most expensive equipment closest to the track.

The railroad track does not curve at the data collection site.

I have been searching for some sort of geometric explanation for this data (i.e., as the train approaches, the sound is being picked up at different distances, but the closest one should still have the highest dB, right?)

At this point, the best explanation I can come up with is some sort of echo phenomenon that caused the sound wave to bounce off of an object behind all three pieces of equipment which then deteriorated rapidly as it made it's way back towards the track.

**What could cause the data I have?**

Comment: At nighttime, sound may get refracted back to earth. Then sound level decreases more slowly with distance to the source. If there was a wall or something in between, a path through the sky might skip that barrier.

Comment: Have you checked that the microphones record the same noise level if you place them next to each another?

Comment: Although this doesn't answer the question, also consider that a train functions more like a line source of sound rather than a point source, so the falloff isn't as quick as with a point source

Comment: Also note that the mics might have been overwhelmed by sound transmission coming up out of the earth. Also were the mics set to flat response, or were they weighted per A, B, or C response curves?

Comment: @gridalien Niels Nielsen has several excellent questions. In addition: how long were your measurements made for? Were there other sound sources present during the course of the measurement? Was there any change in elevation along your microphone transect? (I know there's often a ditch adjacent to the tracks.)

Comment: @D.Betchkal, these are all great questions, but unfortunately I don't know the answers to them. They just handed me the data. I wasn't there when they did this. I do know the measurements were made for 45 continuous minutes, and it may have been windy. I believe the mics were flat response, but I must confirm.